# How to fix "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Timestamp' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I'm new in web development and I'm trying to make a firebase app with the firestore database. I have a user registration form and in this form I need to get the date. For the date I used datepicker but I can't get the selected date and after transform it into firestore Timestamp. I tried this but I don't know if something is correct:

Html form:

```
<input class="datepicker" type="text" id="subscriptionDeadline" placeholder="Subscription Deadline">
```

Javascript code:

```
  var currentDate = $(".subscriptionDeadline").datepicker("getDate");
  var timeStamp = new firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(currentDate);
```

I get this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Timestamp' of undefined

Comment: It sounds like `firebase.firestore` is not correct imported. Be sure to follow the instructions given here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize. If you can't get it to work, make sure to show the minimal-but-complete code that reproduces the problem. For example: you could try to reproduce it in a site like jsbin, and share that here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is `Cannot read property 'Timestamp' of undefined`. In the code, it is trying to access `firebase.firestore.Timestamp`.

The error is saying that whatever you are trying to read the property `Timestamp` from, is undefined. In your case it is `firebase.firestore`. If you do a `console.log(firebase.firestore)` it will show undefined, which means you won't be able to access the Timestamp property or anything else.

It sounds like the problem is you haven't initialized firestore properly on your page. Make sure you have followed these steps: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-mobile-web#set_up_your_development_environment

Comment: Thanks, yeah I noticed it now, I thought it was a different problem but I still can't get the date.